# Sending images and text filed formdata ajax to php. images not identified by php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have input text boxes of type text and one input text box of type file.I want to send these values to php file via ajax when a button is clicked. Everything seems well but for some crazy reason the image if not identified in the php file. 
Kindly help, am out of ideas. My code is as below.

=========javascript code when a button if id=Saved is clicked====

```
 $("#saved").on('click',function(){
$("#itemform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
 });
    var item_desc =document.getElementById("item_desc").value;
 var item_price_type =document.getElementById("item_price_type").value;
 var item_regular_price =document.getElementById("item_regular_price").value;
 var item_type =document.getElementById("item_type").value;
 var item_cat =document.getElementById("item_cat").value;
 var taxablee =document.getElementById("taxablee").value;
 var item_price_tax =document.getElementById("item_price_tax").value;
 var item_offer_price=document.getElementById("item_offer_price").value;
 var offer_start =document.getElementById("offer_start").value;
 var offer_end =document.getElementById("offer_end").value;
var file =document.getElementById('file').value;
var price_tax="";
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('file',file);
formdata.append('item_desc',item_desc);
formdata.append('item_price_type',item_price_type);
formdata.append('item_regular_price',item_regular_price);
formdata.append('item_type',item_type);
formdata.append('item_cat',item_cat);
formdata.append('taxablee',taxablee);
formdata.append('price_tax',price_tax);
formdata.append('item_offer_price',item_offer_price);
formdata.append('offer_start',offer_start);
formdata.append('offer_end',offer_end); 
});
```

============php file to insert data into database===========

```
  $item_desc =$_POST['item_desc'];
  $item_price_type=$_POST['item_price_type'];
  $item_regular_price=$_POST['item_regular_price'];
  $item_type=$_POST['item_type'];
   $item_cat=$_POST['item_cat'];
   $taxablee=$_POST['taxablee'];
  $price_tax=$_POST['price_tax'];
  $item_offer_price=$_POST['item_offer_price'];
   $offer_start=$_POST['offer_start'];
  $offer_end=$_POST['offer_end'];
   $item_image = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   $folder = "../menu_images/";
  $pics =time().$item_image;
 //$sq="// this is my insert statment";
  //$sq_insert =$conn->prepare($sq);
  //$sq_insert->execute(array(//these are my array values for the insert 
    statment));
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $folder.$pics);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use just a html form to submit your data, no need to use javascript for that.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: i have some validations which required javascript

Comment: Don't see any of those in your given code. But you can still use javascript to validate the form before submit.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var form = $('form')[0]; // You need to use standard javascript object here
var formData = new FormData(form);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('section', 'general');
formData.append('action', 'previewImg');
// Attach file
formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 


$.ajax({
    url: 'Your url here',
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS (requires jQuery 1.6+)
    processData: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS
});
```